# In app purchase

Tags: iphone, storekit

I want to use the in-app purchase in my app. Right now, I've created the half portion of my app. As far as I know there are two ways to deliver the app to the buyer using the in-app purchase. The first one is by creating your app fully functional, then if your app wasn't yet purchased, some features of this app should be locked and if it was been purchased it should be unlocked the features. The second way was by using a server side delivery.. I don't need to mention about it .

I'm planning to use the first one, but I got a confusions in my mind. If I use the first one, this means that even if my app was purchased or not, the Binary file was still the same. Is it safe if I use that one, If it my app was already complete, Pirates would think a way to hack it.

I've another question. I'm planning to divide my app in three products. The first part had the commonly use items of my target user. The second one was the commonly use with the second useful items. And the third one contains the two parts plus the third useful items. I'm planning to cost them by these:

```
First =====> $5

Second====> $5

Third =====> $5
```

Which means if a user purchase the first it will cost him $5. If he then purchases the second it will only cost him $5 since he have already purchased the first part.

In other case (user doesn't purchased any), if he select to purchase the second it will cost him $10 because he does not have any purchased item.

Is it possible to do with Store kit frameWork..

BTW I'm planning to release first the first one. And on the other time second one will follow which contains the first and the second items. And then the third one will go if the app will be clicked for my target users

I want to do this to give the users a choice of what they only needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about pirates, no matter what you do they will figure out a way to steal your app (or buy only one copy).

Comment: Amen, the best way to deal with piracy is to understand it will happen no matter what you do.  People have experimented with iPhone apps detecting pirated versions and having gentle pleas informing the user that their actions have real bottom line effects, and if they like the app, please buy it.

Comment: +1 for realism - there is no way to entirely prevent this issue

Comment: I met a woman with a related story. They had some in-app mechanism to find pirates, and if so, the app automagically posted tweets like "I am a thief". Now one day this mechanism went wrong and posted those tweets for legitimate users/customers as well, and then all hell broke loose. Check it out http://www.enfour.com/OpenLetter.pdf