# Mac App Store - store in app purchases

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

What is the best-practice way of storing non-consumable (and consumable) purchases in a Mac App Store app? Different from iOS, it's very easy to access the keychain so I guess that cannot be used.

This answer is kind of right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732389/129202

Still, is there some way that does not take "too much" effort (for me, not the cheaters), ;-)

Update: Reading here and there my current approach will be: Use the keychain, but generate a password that is a mixture (maybe a hash) of device mac address + product id and maybe some salt...

Comment: Did you find any solution? We faced same problem. "generate a password that is a mixture (maybe a hash) of device mac address + product id and maybe some salt" - can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: The app in question never reached daylight so I don't have a "I ended up doing this" answer. Anyway as I stated as a possible approach, the password to save would use the network interface mac address, the product id (I guess appleid or bundleid could be used) of the app, and then some salt. Just concatenate all into a string and then hash that (md5 or something). This means you cannot (easily) move a saved purchase from one device to another. For a normal user, it's just a matter of redownloading the IAP in the app. A hacker would have to find out a lot more :-)